# React app with Parent calling AJAX request and then child component calling another ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

So say I have a React parent component that does an AJAX request on the `componentDidMount` that sets state and then in the render I have a child component that will be taking some of that data from the state and will be doing another AJAX request inside the child component with that information, how do I go about this?

For instance:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { num: '' };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/urltogetdata',
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (this.isMounted()) {
          this.setState({num: data['num']});
        }
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child num={this.state.num}/>
      </div>
    );
  },
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { childInfo: {} };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/urltogetdata/' + this.props.num,
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if (this.isMounted()) {
          this.setState({childInfo: data});
        }
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  renderChildChild: function() {
    return (<div><ChildChild /></div>);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.childInfo.map(this.renderChildChild)}
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

Now the problem I'm getting is that all these renders are happening before I get information. I can usually get the data and display it on the Parent side, but when it gets back down to the Child with the Parent's state (that is set from the AJAX request), I lose a render when I try to setState, because it is already set.

I've tried it with shouldComponentUpdate, componentWillUpdate and various other things and I'm at a loss. I don't really know what else to try or if it's just something I have to deal with because AJAX and asynchronous rendering in React just isn't there yet?

Comment: does "various other things" include `componentWillReceiveProps()`?

Comment: what do you mean by "I lose a render?"

Comment: I mean I lose a render because it doesn't have the correct information to render that component at the time. And I tried `componentWillRecieveProps` before and it didn't work, but I just tried it again but adding some more checking inside the render and it seems to have worked correctly.

Comment: @jamby did you finally find a solution ?